# Weird result in decimal math operation in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I am doing following operation in Javascript and I am getting weird results, can someone tell me what is going on.

```
5.62-6.18+0.56 = 4.440892098500626e-16
```

Comment: This is normal, and not weird.  Same thing will happen in C# etc,.  Some decimal number just cannot be expressed exactly using IEEE format.

Answer (score 0):

Because of floating point inaccuracies, the result isn't exactly zero. JavaScript uses scientific notation to display numbers as small as this one. You might be interested in the [`toPrecision()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toprecision.asp) method.